# display a list values as a sequence of string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like

```
L=[[w,['0','0']],[r,['1']]]
```

I want to print it as

```
w = 00
r = 1
```

for getting  this I tried like

```
for k in range(1,len(tab[0]))
    print L[0][k][0],"=",(L[0][k][1])
```

but it prints like

```
w = ['0','0']
r = ['1']
```

can anyone help me? thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
In [5]: L=[['w',['0','0']],['r',['1']]]

In [6]: L1 = [item for item in L]

In [7]: L1
Out[7]: [['w', ['0', '0']], ['r', ['1']]]

In [8]: ['%s=%s' % (item[0], ''.join(item[1])) for item in L1]
Out[8]: ['w=00', 'r=1']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how do I convert `['0', '0']` to `00` then you may use `join`

```
for k in range(1,len(tab[0]))
    print L[0][k][0],"=", ''.join((L[0][k][1]))
```

I don't fully understand the `for` loop (because I don't know what `tab` is) but to get string representation of a list, use [join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Your list is wrong. Unless w and r are predefined variables, it should read as:

```
L=[['w',['0','0']],['r',['1']]]
```

In that case, the following will achieve the result:
for item in L:

```
print(item[0], ''.join(item[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `for`-loop with string formatting:

```
L = [['w', ['0','0']], ['r',['1']]]
for item in L:
    print '{} = {}'.format(item[0], ''.join(item[1]))
```

What `''.join()` does it joins every item in the list separated by the `''` (i.e nothing). So:

```
['0', '0'] --> '00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with this..

```
L=[[w,['0','0']],[r,['1']]]

for item in L:
    print item[0], '=', ''.join(item[1])


Ans:
   w = 00
   r = 1
```